# Android: TextView does not respect android:TextViewStyle using appcompat-v7 22.1.1

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I have overridden the `Textview` color using the below code that code is working fine in lower version of appcompat-v7 22.1 after i update to support repository these one not working. Any idea on these?

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/AppTheme.TextView</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.TextView" parent="android:Widget.TextView">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
</style>
```

Comment: What error you are getting? add your logs/error info.

Comment: I am not getting any error that "textViewStyle" alone getting skipped and color given is not setting in the TextView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In appcompat-v7 22.1.1 they not defined the "textViewStyle" for TextView seems refer following link for details
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=170476